# When should we ask questions on Reddit?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-crossover

I recently involve more in Reddit, and surprisingly find out a subreddit named [AskAcademia](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia/). I know that Stack Exchange is not Reddit, and the way Reddit works is different to the way SE works. In SE, people ask and answer. In Reddit, people post a link/thinking and comment. However, in Q&A subreddit like AskAcademia, I see no different to here. Bad questions may never be closed, but they will never be raised. Can you tell me when should I ask questions on Reddit rather than Stack Exchange?

Comment: There's also ResearchGate.

Comment: @gerrit ResearchGate is where questions go to die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Reddit

- Born for open-ended discussions
- After 6 months posts are automatically locked so discussions are "fossilized" to reflect what happened in that time
- No way for users to improve others' posts
- Downvotes can (and usually?) mean "I don't like this" or "this is uninteresting"
- The only way to have links to relevant posts within the subreddit is by having other users provide
- More active users in my opinion

## Stack Exchange

- Born for Q&A
- Posts can always be improved until the Sun dies
- Contributions from users are encouraged and peer-reviewed
- Downvotes mean "This post is wrong/not useful"
- Have tag system, related questions to categorize and discover more questions/answers
- Posts can have images, HTML. The site overall is nicely designed

Comment: Posts can be improved... until the site gets shut down. Which could (theoretically) happen tomorrow.

Comment: Theoretically, the Sun could shut down tomorrow too.

Answer (score 16):

You should ask a question on Reddit whenever you feel like it, regardless of whether you ask the question on Academia.SE.

Academia.SE doesn't make any claim to be the only site you should ask a question on.  It only asks that you not ask the same question on any other SE site, because that is general SE policy.

Comment: I know that Reddit doesn't have so much restrictions. I want to know which questions would be best to ask here, not there. The restrictions of Stack Exchange are born with reason anyway.

Comment: Though as a courtesy to potential answerers, it is a good idea to mention the cross-posting both places, to avoid duplication of effort.